# Appending Smarty Script into the DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

my problem is that my smarty script wont work when appending it to the DOM using after() jquery, I use this script when user tries to add new item and just by inserting it after the last table row.

> in PHP

```
var smartyFetchItem = '{section name=cnt loop=$ItemsVal}<option value="{$ItemsVal[cnt].itemname}" >{$ItemsVal[cnt].itemname}</option>{/section}';

    $('tbody.tbodyruler tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="ds" name="itemname[]"><select class="itemanm"><option value="others">If Others - Please fill up add info</option>'+smartyFetchItem+'</select></td><td><input type="text" name="addinfo[]" id="addinfo[]" value="none"></td><td><input class="spinner" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" value="1"></td><td></td><td><input type="hidden" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice[]" class="unitprice"></td><td></td><td><input type="hidden" name="total[]" id="total[]" class="subtot" readonly></td></tr>');
```

> in TPL

```
<tbody class="tbodyruler">

    {section name=count loop=$counter}
      <tr>

        <td><input type="hidden" id="ds" name="itemname[]">
        <select class="itemanm">
            <option value="others">If Others - Please fill up add info</option>
            {section name=cnt loop=$ItemsVal}
            <option value="{$ItemsVal[cnt].itemname}" >{$ItemsVal[cnt].itemname}</option>
            {/section}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="addinfo[]" id="addinfo[]" value="none"></td>
        <td><input class="spinner" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" value="1"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice[]" class="unitprice"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="total[]" id="total[]" class="subtot" readonly></td>

      </tr>

      {/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var smartyFetchItem = '';       
    {section name=cnt loop=$ItemsVal} {literal}
        smartyFetchItem =  smartyFetchItem + '<option value="{$ItemsVal[cnt].itemname}" >{$ItemsVal[cnt].itemname}</option>';
    {/section}

    $('tbody.tbodyruler tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="ds" name="itemname[]"><select class="itemanm"><option value="others">If Others - Please fill up add info</option>'+smartyFetchItem+'</select></td><td><input type="text" name="addinfo[]" id="addinfo[]" value="none"></td><td><input class="spinner" name="quantity[]" id="quantity[]" value="1"></td><td></td><td><input type="hidden" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice[]" class="unitprice"></td><td></td><td><input type="hidden" name="total[]" id="total[]" class="subtot" readonly></td></tr>');
```